# "deadlock victim" in transaction, how to change the priority?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deadlock, ssms, database-deadlocks

i have logged an exception thrown by an ASP.NET-Application.

> Message: Transaction (Process ID 56)
>   was deadlocked on lock | communication
>   buffer resources with another process
>   and has been chosen as the deadlock
>   victim. Rerun the transaction.

I'm sure that the reason for it was, that i was running some `selects` directly in SSMS on tables that were queried in the application in the same time.

So now my question is:

- Can i change the priority SQL-Server chooses "deadlock victims"? I would like to choose "myself" (SSMS) as deadlock victim and not ASP.NET, because it's a time-critical application and it's easier for me to rerun the manual query than for the users to accept an error.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186736%28SQL.90%29.aspx) allows you to fine tune the precedence

You can specify this in your SSMS session (per query window) or globally:

[image: Tools..Options..etc]

Comment: Thank you. That means i can change it to `Low` to reduce the priority of SSMS-Queries? That would work for me. Are there other options to fine-tune the deadlock-priorities? I've read that SQL-Server chooses deadlock victims on the effort to rollback a transaction by default. Is that correct?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Yes to "low" for SSMS queries. No to other options. Victims are chosen on least resource to roll back as per my link above: "If both sessions have the same deadlock priority, the instance of SQL Server chooses the session that is less expensive to roll back as the deadlock victim." Cheers

Comment: Curse at MS Dynamics NAV for not letting this be changed inside their C/AL code. If it's between a user and an unattended process (which can retry on failure) I'd prefer the unattended process to "lose".