# How to prevent locks/delays when querying the same tables from different processes?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2005, transactions, parallel-processing

I have an issue that people can't work with an intranet application that is querying the same tables that i'm querying from SQL Server Management Studio. They must wait until the query finished what can last ~10 minutes.

I've already [reduced the deadlock-priority of SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290114/deadlock-victim-in-transaction-how-to-change-the-priority/6290192#6290192) but that seems to have no effect on the delays now.

I would think it should be possible that SQL-Server could handle both queries parallel or at least have an option to reduce SSMS' priority. So is there any way/option to ensure that some processes like `w3sp.exe` get high-priority and other "internal"(SSMS related queries) get low-priority in processor time? The server wasn't busy at all, only 6% CPU was used, why is this so? Also, why does SQL-Server seem to lock tables that are queried without any changes(updates/deletes). Can i avoid that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Um, `sqlservr.exe` is the SQL Server process itself - you wouldn't want it getting low priority. `ssms.exe` would be management studio.

Comment: Do you have examples of the queries you are running in SSMS?  SQL Server is designed for concurrent processes on the same tables, with various levels of isolation depending on settings, hints, the operations being performed, etc.

Comment: @Dems: that wouldn't be very helpful since i'm querying several joinded views which, for their part are querying  a table that is also queried by the intranet application(read-only).

Comment: If both the intranet app and the SSMS queries are only performing selects, then something very odd is happening here.

Comment: @Damien,@Dems: You are correct. One of the views in my SSMS-Query is also querying a table that might get changed from the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that you could reduce the transaction isolation level for some/all of the read-only operations being performed by either or both of the intranet application and your SSMS queries. But if you do this, you have to be wary of such things as dirty reads (where you read one or more rows from a table and these rows later turns out not to be committed by their owning transaction).

There are no priority level settings for connections within SQL Server (other than, as you've noted, volunteering to be the deadlock victim). OS level settings (e.g. process priorities) will have no effect on SQL Server - all it cares about are locks, and whether these locks are compatible between different connections.

---

You can use the [`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) statement to change your isolation at the connection level, or you can use [locking hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) (such as `WITH NOLOCK`) on individual tables within statements to have more granular control over what locks are being taken.

Note, though, that if you're running DML statements (e.g. INSERT or DELETE), these will still need to take exclusive locks, so if your intranet application wishes to query the same tables, it had to wait for the DML statement to complete, or it has to be modified to relaz its isolation. There's no means to specify the behaviour of *other* connections from your own queries - they have to choose their own isolation settings.

Comment: thank you for clarifying that the transaction isolation level is the decisive criterion. I would love to see an example on how to change the transaction level for SSMS-queries(or if there is a global setting in SSMS, i would prefer that), because changing the application's would be much more work.

Comment: One of the views in SSMS is also querying a table that might get changed from the app. That explains why the app-transaction must wait until my query has finished.

Comment: As i've understood from your answer i could `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` on my SSQM-Query that quries a table that might get changed from another transaction(the app). But that wouldn't prevent the app from beeing locked until my query has finished, am i correct? So using `WITH (NOLOCK)` on the table that is causing the lock in my query would allow the app to write to this table, is this correct? I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require to change the application.

Comment: @Tim: If the SSMS queries are always read-only, using NOLOCK should indeed allow the Application's write operations to progress.