# Setting a deadlock victim

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sitecore, sitecore6

We're using siteCore 6.5 and each time we start to publish items, users who are browsing the website will get server 500 errors which end up being

> Transaction (Process ID ##) was deadlocked on lock resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.

How can we setup SQL Server to give priority to a specific application? We cannnot modify any queries or code so it has to be done via SQL Server (or connection string)

I've seen ["deadlock victim" in transaction, how to change the priority?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290114/deadlock-victim-in-transaction-how-to-change-the-priority) and looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186736(v=SQL.105).aspx but these seem to be per session, not globally.

I don't care if it's a fix/change to SiteCore or a SQL solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set the deadlock priority globally - it's a session-only setting. There are not any connection string settings that I know of. The list of possible SqlConnection string settings can be found [here](http://connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords).

Comment: this is what i'm finding too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're actually having a problem with the cache and every time you publish, it's clearing the cache and thus you're getting deadlocks with all these calls made at the same time.  I haven't seen this sort of thing happen with 6.5 so you might also want to check into your caching.  It would help a lot to look at your Sitecore logs and see if this is happening when caches are being created.  Either way, check the caching guide on the SDN and see if that helps.

Comment: Already determined the caache isn't being cleared until the process is finished. This was tested with the sitecore pulbish. We wrote our own publish framework which garuntees that no events are fired until all items are published. But our system still uses SiteCore publish manager to do the actual publish so we're still relying on sitecore's queries.