# Can I SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY via SqlConnection in .NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, deadlock

Can I set the DEADLOCK_PRIORITY for a stored procedure via a SqlConnection or some other means in my .NET programm? Or does it only work via a

```
 SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY...
```

call in the stored procedure itself?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a connection just execute

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY...
```

For example:

```
dim cn as new SqlConnection(cstring)
Dim cmd as SQlCommand=cn.CreateConnection
cmd.CommandText="SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY NORMAL"
cn.Open
cmd.Execute
```

What is set remains valid until connection is closed.

There is no option to set DEADLOCK_PRIORITY - see [All SQL Server SqlConnection properties](http://connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords) or [Setting a deadlock victim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346810/setting-a-deadlock-victim)